# Twilio Carrier lookup Enum?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm struggling to locate a reference for the Carrier strings that can be returned from the Twilio phone-number lookup API.

For a problem I'm working on, I need to know the full set of possible values but API docs appear sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We don't provide a list of all carrier names for this use. From [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api#lookups-carrier-info):

> Please bear in mind that carriers rebrand themselves constantly and that the names used for carriers will likely change over time.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Any idea whether MVNO's come through or if the underlying network shows in the response? E.g. "Straight Talk" runs on Verizon.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I use an MVNO and I just checked and the underlying network showed. I can't guarantee that's the case for all MVNOs though. I'm checking with the team, but haven't heard anything yet.

Comment: Any word on whether/how mvno's can come through?

Comment: I believe that the carrier will be the underlying carrier, however you also get a `mobile_country_code` field, which is more specific. If you need, you can compare those codes against the carrier here: http://mcc-mnc.com/